# How to find nested image on phoenix?

Tags: jquery-ui, elixir, phoenix-framework

I use jQuery Mobile UI. It include css and some image file.
The following error was caused.

```
** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /css/images/ajax-loader.gif
```

Then I make a directory inside of assets css directory and put target image file.

```
/assets/css/images/ajax-loader.gif
```

However it still happen same error. How can I set values?
One I know is setting plug Plug.Static in `endpoint.ex`.

I have no idea.

Comment: are you using `brunch`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in the CSS directory will not be served directly, they need to go through a frontend build tool first (brunch by default). So whether this can work depends on your setup. Brunch for example does not copy these files by default.

There's a simpler solution to serve static assets though: put your static images in `assets/static/images/`, then you can just load them from `/images/ajax-loader.gif`.

You could also put them in `assets/static/css/images/` and access them via the exact path you mentioned above - although this is not the standard approach - that's what the `assets/static/images/` folder is for.

If you're including jquery-mobile via brunch, you could for example copy the files with [copycat-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copycat-brunch) (brunch will not copy assets from node_modules by itself), for example:

Install copycat-brunch:

```
npm install --save copycat-brunch
```

Example configuration (might need some adjustments):

```
// in brunch-config.js

plugins: {
  copycat: {
    "images": [
      ["../priv/static/assets/css/images/", "node_modules/jquery-mobile/path/to/images"]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This `/assets/css/images/ajax-loader.gif` request comes from jQuery mobile style sheet. I can't alter that file. How can I change path for `ajax-loader.gif` ?

Comment: How are you including jquery mobile, via brunch?

Comment: If so, you might want to use copycat-brunch to copy the files from node_modules to the proper destination. You should then copy to `priv/static` directly.

Comment: I did not know how to use priv directory. I have no idea of difference between priv and assets.

Comment: Well you should not copy files manually to priv/static, let brunch do it for you. See my edit